# Facebook::Graph for number of likes

Tags: facebook, perl

Can I use Facebook::Graph to retrieve the number of likes without dealing with authorization tokens?  The following code:

```
use Facebook::Graph;
my $fb = Facebook::Graph->new;
my $hashref = $fb->query
    ->request('https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor')
    ->as_hashref;
```

produces the following error:

Unable to create sub named ""

I'm not a real perl coder so I may be way off.

http://search.cpan.org/~rizen/Facebook-Graph-1.0501/lib/Facebook/Graph.pm

Answer (score 0):

You can. Your problem is that btaylor is a regular facebook user and users cannot be liked. For objects that can be liked you can query for a list of likes following the example below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/thagroggs
```

Comment: Is an access token the same as an authorization token?  For simplicity I'm trying to retrieve this info without access control since it is public: http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url="http://www.facebook.com/amazon" My btaylor example errors with just the code above which does not incorporate likes and which was pulled straight from the CPAN page so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: As far as I know an access token is the same as an authorization token. I'm not familiar with a lot of the language in you comment "access control", "CPAN". But to elaborate on my answer facebook ID btaylor is not a likable facebook object so you wouldn't be able to query it for likes.

Comment: I'm confused because your answer "You can" indicates that I can retrieve the number of likes without an authorization token, but the URL you posted requires an access token.  Is an access token required to retrieve the number of likes via the API even though this info is freely available via XML at the following address: http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url="http://www.facebook.com/amazon" ?  Also, I get the same error as in my original post when using amazon instead of btaylor with the code from my original post.

Comment: Ahh I missed that part of your post. I've changed my example to show a token free call to a facebook page that will show number of likes.

Comment: Ben, I'm not trying to give you a hard time but I'm wondering if this can be done via Facebook::Graph without a token.

Comment: Did you try change I made to my answer?

Comment: If I use your URL in my code in place of the URL in my question, I get: Unable to create sub named "".  I can access the URL in a browser and it displays the number of likes but I'm trying to retrieve that number with Facebook::Graph.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. Are you able to make any facebook graph calls with your code?

Comment: All I've been able to get from the Facebook::Graph perl module is that error unfortunately.

Comment: I'm working with the Facebook::Graph author on this.  I'll report back when I have more info.